# Converting the code from vbscript to Jscript?

Tags: javascript, vbscript, wmi, user-profile

How do I convert the following VBScript code to JScript which is used for getting the user profile paths for all users?

```
Set oWshNet = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
sComputer = oWshNet.ComputerName
'For remote computer
'sComputer = "some name or IP"
Const HKLM = &H80000002

sProfileRegBase = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" 
Set oReg = GetObject("WinMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//" _ 
                & sComputer & "/root/default:StdRegProv")
Set oWMI = GetObject("WinMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//" _ 
                & sComputer & "/root/cimv2")
Set colItems = oWMI.ExecQuery _ 
                ("Select Name,SID from Win32_UserAccount WHERE Domain = '" _ 
                & sComputer & "'",,48)
For Each oItem In colItems
  sAddInfo = ""
  Wscript.Echo "User name: " & oItem.Name & sAddInfo
  oReg.GetExpandedStringValue HKLM, sProfileRegBase& "\" & oItem.SID, _ 
                  "ProfileImagePath", sProfilePath
  If IsNull(sProfilePath) Then
    sProfilePath = "(none defined)"
  End If <br>
  Wscript.Echo "Profile path: " & sProfilePath
  Wscript.Echo   ' blank line
Next
```

I was partially succeeded in converting but stuck at 2 things.

1. Please confirm whether my usage of `oReg = GetObject("WinMgmts:\\\\.\\root\\default:StdRegProv");` is correct and is same as the one that was given in the code. If not please suggest the right usage.
2. What is the equivalent for `GetExpandedStringValue` in JScript? If there is none, what is the better way to validate if a registry key exists before getting the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample solution: (from http://www.windowsitpro.com/content/content/93402/Listing_05.txt)

```
// GetSystemPath.js

var HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002;
var ENVIRONMENT_SUBKEY = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control"
  + "\\Session Manager\\Environment";

var computer, regprov, method, inparams, outparams, systempath;

// CALLOUT A
// Step 1: Get an instance of the WMI object.
computer = ".";
regprov = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationlevel=impersonate}!//"
  + computer + "/root/default:StdRegProv");
// END CALLOUT A

// CALLOUT B
// Step 2: Create an InParameters object for the method.
method = regprov.Methods_.Item("GetExpandedStringValue");
inparams = method.InParameters.SpawnInstance_();
// END CALLOUT B

// CALLOUT C
// Step 3: Set the InParameters object's properties.
inparams.hDefKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
inparams.sSubKeyName = ENVIRONMENT_SUBKEY;
inparams.sValueName = "Path";
// END CALLOUT C

// CALLOUT D
// Step 4: Call ExecMethod_ to return an OutParameters object.
outparams = regprov.ExecMethod_(method.Name, inparams);
// END CALLOUT D

// CALLOUT E
// Step 5: The OutParameters object contains the method's results.
if (outparams.ReturnValue == 0) {
  systempath = outparams.sValue;
  WScript.Echo(systempath);
}
// END CALLOUT E
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Pl confirm is my usage of oReg = GetObject("WinMgmts:\.\root\default:StdRegProv"); is correct and is same as the one that was given in the code? if not please suggest the right usage?

Both forward slashes (`/`) and backslashes (`\`) will work in this case. However, backslashes will need to be doubled since they are special characters in JScript.

> 2) what is the similar function for GetExpandedStringValue in Jscirpt? If there none, what is the better way to validate if a registry key exists before getting the value?

Actually, you can use `StdRegProv.GetExpandedStringValue` in JScript, even though this method uses an `out` parameter and JScript doesn't natively support `out` parameters. The trick is to call it via the [`ExecMethod_`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393774.aspx). See [Writing WMI Scripts in JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394616.aspx) for an explanation and example.

Answer (score 0):

Any string with a \ character needs to be escaped so;

```
var sProfileRegBase = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\ProfileList"
```

This includes your `GetObject()` call.

`GetExpandedStringValue` is the same; its not a VB function, its a method of the "Wscript.Network" object so is available to js.

Comment: oops! The \ you see because of my poor editing here. I used GetExpandedStringValue but it is returning null for sProfilePath although it exists.. I used the function as oReg.GetExpandedStringValue(HKLM, sProfileRegBase + "\\" + objEnum.SID, "ProfileImagePath", sProfilePath); where objEnum is the enumerator object for the collection items of the query oWMI.ExecQuery("Select Name,SID from Win32_UserAccount");